# mongod on Ubuntu 14.04LTS autostart on reboot

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu-14.04

This is crazy - I've gone around-and-around on this. From the command line, I can call the following successfully:

sudo service mongod --dbpath "/var/lib/mongodb" --auth

I have tried at least a dozen variations of trying to get mongo to auto-start on boot with no success. I tried a script with the above line and put in init.d...I tried systemctl - but that is not recognized as a command. etc...
I have configured /etc/mongod.conf - but that does not appear to be used, as a simple mongod call says it can't find the database in /data/db/ ...
I used a simple apt-get to install this, but can only run it from the command line, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I assume you've tried cron?

Comment: You can ask an ubuntu package supporter why mongod doesn't start after you install it with _apt-get_ or what adjustments should be done for it to start.